# MySQL: More Columns vs. More Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to design a rather large database to handle videos and their tags. Because only a finite number of tags can be selected for a video (27) I am storing them in a table 28 columns wide (one column for each tag + the video_id).

My problem arises when I want to get the number of times a user has liked/disliked a video with a certain tag (lets say #24). Each Like/Dislike gets a row in another table.

Here are the two options I've considered.

**1) Add 27 more tinyint columns to the User Table**, each one representing the number of times he's voted on a video with tagX.
PRO: Easily Selected
CON: Doubles the amount of data needed for each user

**2) Use Inner Joins**
PRO: Keeps size small
CON: Harder on the system

Both because I'm optomistic and because I'm trying to use good practice, I'm trying to optimize my databases for 300,000+ users, and these numbers will be needed a lot. I Did the math and even with 300,000 users it would only add about 27 megabytes to my database.

What to do!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

27 columns to user table only work if you have 27 different tags. So, adding another tag requries schema change (which is a bad thing).

I vote for something like this:

```
table users(
   user_id
  ,primary key(user_id)
);

table videos(
   video_id
  ,primary key(video_id)
);

table tags(
   tag_id
  ,tag_name
  ,primary key(tag_id)
);

table video_tags(
   video_id
  ,tag_id
  ,primary key(video_id, tag_id)
);

table user_likes(
   user_id
  ,video_id
  ,primary key(user_id, video_id)
);
```

To show the number of votes per tag, you would do something like this:

```
select c.tag_name
      ,count(*)
  from user_likes a
  join video_tags b uing(video_id)
  join tags       c using(tag_id)
 where a.user_id = ?
 group 
    by c.tag_name;
```

Answer (score 4):

(this is just my opinion)

I think you're optimizing too early (and probably incorrectly).  Joins are not that expensive.  You should have a users table, a tags table and a like table.  Depending on your exact queries, you will probably find this marginally less expensive.

You are better off spending time ensuring you have the right indexes than creating a layout designed for performance over maintainence.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll definitely be doing this

Answer (score 1):

Your denormazling rationality is flawed. Today you might think that 27 videos is the maximum but there will always be another one or two or more in the future.